# SFTP wont work when running on server but will when doing it through driver

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a send method which works and sends a file through SFTP when i run it through a test driver. It draws server properties from a sftp.properties file in directory within eclipse. However when I run it using Maven and hit the ftpToJSON.json page it wont run and it gives me the stack trace

i have no idea why it wont work

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:Properties/db.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:Properties/sftp.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>



public boolean send(String fileName) {

    props = new Properties();
    String propertiesFilename = "src/main/resources/Properties/sftp.properties";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

    System.out.println("preparing the host information for sftp.");
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFilename));
        String SFTPHOST = props.getProperty("SFTPHOST").trim();
        int SFTPPORT = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("SFTPPORT").trim());
        String SFTPUSER = props.getProperty("SFTPUSER").trim();
        String SFTPPASS = props.getProperty("SFTPPASS").trim();
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = props.getProperty("SFTPWORKINGDIR").trim();


        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
```

Comment: Is the file src\main\resources\Properties\sftp.properties  available when you're running it via a web-server?

Comment: hmmm how do we check, what i am assuming is when it's running it is not... how do we go about solving it with if its not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `src/main/resources/Properties/sftp.properties` to access properties. Better is to go via the following:

```java
InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Properties/sftp.properties");
```

which will be the way to do it.

Comment: should this fix the issue?